# Imprimir de php a diferentes mini-printers

Tags: php, print

Hola estoy realizando un proyecto con php, mysql que usa mini-printers... hasta ahora ya logre imprimir en la maquina servirdor que se llama "**SERVER**" y la impresora se llama "**PRINT1**", este es el codigo que uso y todo bien

```
require '../LIB_IMPRIMIR/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://SERVER/PRINT1");
$printer   = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> text("HOLA\n");
$printer -> feed();
$printer -> cut();  
$printer -> close();
exit();
```

pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es mandar a imprimir a otras mini-printer que estan conectadas a otras maquinas:"Maquina1", "Maquina2", etc cada una con una mini-printer, pero no logro mandar a imprimir el codigo que uso es algo asi

```
require '../LIB_IMPRIMIR/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://MAQUINA1/PRINT2");
$printer   = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> text("HOLA\n");
$printer -> feed();
$printer -> cut();  
$printer -> close();
exit();
```

¿que es lo que me falta o debo hacer?

Comment: podrias verificar si efectivamente se llama asi tanto el PC como la IMPRESORA

Comment: Hola si asi se llama la maquina... de hecho si puedo mandar a imprimir de forma normal..

Comment: me manda el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to copy file to printer' in ...